# Multiple definition files RabbitMQ management

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to import rabbitmq definitions at cluster run. Management definitions files are a pretty good and clean way to do so.

In order to split what my release team set up as default configuration and what the client will define later, I want to split the definitions into two files : broker.definitions.json and clients.definitions.json..

The first one will contain default values for the cluster such as disabling rights to user guest, changing partition handling and so on.
The second will contain definitions of queues, exchange, policies and everything that is related to a specific application or cluster.

By default, this is not possible, because the config file seems to takes only one definition file.

Do you have an idea about how to improve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved here on a pull request : https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/665